# How to rename a file from ext4 file system to ntfs file system in C++

Tags: c++, filesystems

Have a query. I am always using the code in C++ (below) to move a file from one location to another in same drive (call it A drive)

```
rename(const char* old_filename, const char* new_filename);
```

Recently I need to amend the code to move it to another drive (call in B-Drive). It doesn't work but I could write code to write into that particular drive (B-drive). On investigation, I found that the drive (A-drive) on which I produce the result(the old file) is in ext4 file system but the drive i am writing/moving to is in NTFS (fuseblk)

How can i amend my code to move the file to NTFS. I am using C++ in ubuntu

Regards

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

New Edit after heeding call from user4581301

This is the code I have written

```
int main()
{
    std::string dirinADrive = "/home/akaa/data/test3/test_from.txt";                            // this is the parent directory
    std::string dirinBDrive = "/media/akaa/Data/GIRO_repo/working/data/test5/test_to.txt";    // this is where i want to write to
    std::string dirinCDrive = "/home/akaa/data/test3/test_to.txt";                          // this is where i want to write to
    std::string dirinDDrive = "/media/akaa/Data/GIRO_repo/working/data/test5/test_to_write.txt";

    bool ok1{std::ofstream(dirinADrive).put('a')}; // create and write to file
    bool ok2{std::ofstream(dirinDDrive).put('b')}; // create and write to file
    if (!(ok1 && ok2))
    {
       std::perror("Error creating from.txt");
       return 1;
    }

    if (std::rename(dirinADrive.c_str(), dirinCDrive.c_str()))   // moving file to same drive
    {
        std::perror("Error renaming local");
        return 1;
    }


    if (std::rename(dirinADrive.c_str(), dirinBDrive.c_str()))   // moving file to other drive
    {
        std::perror("Error renaming other");
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << std::ifstream(dirinBDrive).rdbuf() << '\n'; // print file
}
```

And I have gotten an error

```
Error renaming other: Invalid cross-device link
```

So what is invalid cross-device link??

Thanks

Comment: Make certain that your system supports writing to NTFS (shouldn't be a problem unless your Ubuntu distribution's more than 10 years old) AND ensure your account has write permissions to the NTFS file system.

Comment: @user4581301: I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I believe I have set the permission to write (as in the same code elsewhere, I have written function to create file). I just do not know what went wrong

Comment: [Put a call to `perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) in after the `rename` fails and see if the error message that comes back contains any useful information. Consider writing a simple program that does nothing but try to move a file. If this also fails, post this simple program (if only so you can say, "I gotcher MCVE right here, punk.") If it doesn't fail, hey, more information to work from.

Comment: @user4581301. Edited my question to incorporate your comments

Comment: That message means for some reason you cannot move the file from drive a to drive b. Not sure why that is, but it'll probably be because you can't make the move atomic. See if you can execute the move from the command line. If you can't, you may be able to get better assistance at [superuser](https://superuser.com/), but since you are moving from one drive to another, you're going to wind up copying anyway. If the move fails, fall back on copy and delete original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t use `rename` across filesystems, because the data must be copied (and having a single system call do an arbitrary amount of work is problematic even without atomicity issues).  You really do have to open the source file and destination file and write the contents of one to the other.  Apply whatever attributes you want to preserve (*e.g.*, with `stat` and `chmod`), then delete the source file if you want.

In C++17, much of this has been packaged as [`std::filesystem::copy_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file).  (There is also `std::filesystem::rename`, but it’s no better than `std::rename` for this case.)